# Akka: What is a best practice to start an Akka process from init.d?

Tags: scala, akka, init.d

I need to start Akka processes as *nix "init.d" (System V or else).

Usually what I do locally it is start one of those like:

```
java -jar myakka-project.jar ....
```

However this is "blocking" on the console as it never forks so it hangs the process in the script (unless I use nohup/&).

What is a "best practice" to start Akka services in init.d?

Comment: Maybe the solution is the "sbt-native-packager" only